# Hay forma de cambiar la estructura del form del formulario sin que se afecte su funcionaliento?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy manejando los mensajes de error mediante la gema *toastr* y una función en *javascript* que trabaja con la gema.

Uno de los parámetros es `resource` y en el formulario partial *_comments* no lo lleva, y está definido así:

```
<%= form_for [*commentable, Comment.new], local: true do |f|  %>
  <%= render 'shared/devisemes' %> //Esto genera error
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_area :body, autofocus: true, :rows => 2, style: 'width:100%;', placeholder: "Add a comment", class: "form-control" %><br/>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Commentate", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"  %>
<% end %>
```

Lógicamente como la función se vale de `resources` genera error ya que no reconoce a `resource`:

```
**undefined local variable or method `resource' for**
```

¿Hay forma de redefinir la siguiente línea:

```
 <%= form_for [*commentable, Comment.new], local: true do |f|  %>
```

de esta forma para que funcione?

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Esté es el código que se invoca en a vistas:

_devisemes.html.erb

```
<% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |value| %>
      toastr.error('<%= value %>')
    <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>

<% unless resource.errors.empty? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |value| %>
      toastr.error('<%= value %>')
    <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Ejemplo de invocación desde un formulario:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

    <h2 class="text-center">Sign up</h2>
    <br/>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:     registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/devisemes' %> //Acá se invoca

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :fullname, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Full Name", class: "form-control" %>
     </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off",  placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[image: Error que genera]

Comment: ¿Qué acción realizas que te devuelve el error?

Comment: @Gerry, ese código reemplaza a los mensajes de error que por defecto maneja el framework,por ejemplo, cuando se da grabar al comentario y está en blanco debe desplegar e mensaje que maneja la validación para datos obligatorios. --->   validates :body, presence: true

Comment: De acuerdo, pero entiendo que te está dando un error (el cual muestras en tu pregunta), ¿cómo llegaste a ese error?.

Comment: Cuando invoco la función el form de comments, el código lo coloqué al principio de la pregunta, en la segunda línea de ese código coloque //Esto genera error.@Gerry, mira que ese form no trae el parámetro resource.

Comment: ¿Tu repositorio está actualizado? He intentado reproducir el error, pero todo me sale bien.

Comment: @Gerry, repositorio actualizado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que `resource` es un *helper* de *Devise* el cual se utiliza para reconocer al usuario (i.e `user`), sin embargo una vez pasado el proceso de *sign up*, este *helper* deja de estar disponible.

En lugar de forzar pasar `resource` como parámetro, podrías intentar con el objeto en cuestión, por ejemplo, `@question`; para ello necesitarás utilizar variables locales en tu parcial, algo similar a esto:

```
<%= render 'shared/devisemes', resource: commentable.last %>
```

De esa forma, `resource` tendrá el objeto `commentable` (el cual puede ser `question` o `answer`) y buscará los errores de ese objeto (en lugar de los de `user`). Esto lo puedes adaptar (utilizando la variable adecuada) para todos los casos que necesites.

---

Una opción (no muy elegante) que pudiera servirte, es pasar el mensaje del primer error con `@comment.errors.full_messages.first` a `flash` y así conseguirías mostrar el mensaje proveniente de la validación al usuario, por ejemplo (en `CommentsController#create`):

```
redirect_to question_path(commentable), flash: { alert: @comment.errors.full_messages.first }
```

Con esta línea ya no necesitarías del parcial *_devisemes.html.erb* en la forma:

```
<%= form_for [*commentable, Comment.new], local: true do |f|  %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_area :body, autofocus: true, :rows => 2, style: 'width:100%;', placeholder: "Add a comment", class: "form-control" %><br/>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Commentate", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"  %>
<% end %>
```

La única desventaja sería que, en caso que se genere más de un error en la validación, sólo verías el primer error.

Comment: Como es para el formulario de comments que usa polimorfismo lo debo pasar como *commentable??, está de la siguiente manera:                                    <%= form_for [*commentable, Comment.new], local: true do |f|  %>               <%= render 'shared/devisemes' %>  ---> <%= render 'shared/devisemes', resource: *commentable %>

Comment: @GarcíaHenry En ese caso tendrías que utilizar `commentable`, pues en esa variable ya tienes el objeto, sin embargo, dado que es un arreglo, podrías utlizar el método `last`, y así obtener el objeto que está siendo comentado; mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: En el controlador le enviaba un mensaje de error, pero lógicamemte creo que ya no debe de ir porque el código que se quiere que maneje los  errores no se desplegaría, pero igual si le quito el mensaje no genera ningún mensaje cuando le doy grabar el comentario: else
       redirect_to question_path(commentable)

Comment: @GarcíaHenry Esto se debe a que el objeto que tiene el error (i.e. `comment`) no está disponible en la acción `show` del controlador `QuestionsController`, por lo tanto los errores que vienen del modelo se pierden. Si quieres evitar esto, debes utilizar `render` en lugar de `redirect_to` en el controlador `CommentsController`, de esa forma te mantienes dentro de la acción de ese controlador y, por lo tanto `@comment` estará disponible en tu vista. El problem ahora será que no podrás ver las preguntas correctamente, pues necesitarías los objetos creados en `Questions#show`.

Comment: @GarcíaHenry Lo mejor que podrías hacer es generar más _partials_ específicos para cada acción, puede que repitas un poco de código, pero el nivel de abstracción que buscas es un poco más elaborado y no es óptimo para aprender. Te recomendaría primero iniciar con un flujo más simple y, cuando ya tengas un mejor entendimiento de _Rails_ busques optimizar tu código. Lo mismo recomendaría para las gemas, trata de hacer tanto como puedas tu y después aprovecha las gemas que ya existen (así aprenderás mejor).

Comment: y especificamente a que vista debería hacer el render para que se quede en el formulario donde se grabó el comentario?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68051/discussion-between-garcia-henry-and-gerry).

Comment: @GarcíaHenry He agregado una opción que podría servir para el propósito que buscas, mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: y precisamete la funcipon del _devisemes.html.erb es que muestre todos los errores posibles de los formularios. Ahora, otro de los requerimientos es que sino está logueado y de clic en cuakquier  flechita salga el mensaje de que para votar necesita estar logueado, pero cuando no está logueado ahí no estoy manejando ninguna accipon, solo muestro la flechita y los datos que debe desplegar.